# How to locate random xpath in selenium ide and webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

In my website there is a form which takes user input in text form

using firepath i traced the xpath of that location

```
.//*[@id='cphSiteContentView_cphContentPanel_ucBookingSummary_ucShoppingCart_rptProductList_ctl00_0_ucTravellersContactDetails_0_rptRoomsDetails_0_rptAdultDetails_0_txtFirstName_0']
```

But when i load the same page again i get the below path

NewXPath=`.//*[@id='cphSiteContentView_cphContentPanel_ucBookingSummary_ucShoppingCart_rptProductList_ctl00_0_ucTravellersContactDetails_0_rptRoomsDetails_0_rptAdultDetails_1_txtFirstName_1']`

On observing the above path i noticed that only the `adultdatails_0_txtFirstname_0` part get get changed to `adultdatails_1_txtFirstname_1`

Note: Every time i get a new number for adultdetails,txtfirstname.

I have tried xpath pattern matching but not get any success. So need help to handle this

any help will be appriciated

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`starts-with()` or `contains()`](http://abodeqa.wordpress.com/2013/01/29/contains-and-starts-with-function-in-xpath/) in xpath,

```
//*[starts-with(@id,'cphSiteContentView_cphContentPanel_ucBookingSummary_ucShoppingCart_rptProductList_ctl00_0_ucTravellersContactDetails_0_rptRoomsDetails_0_rptAdultDetails')]
```

**Or**

If you prefer [`cssSelector`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/css3attributeselectors), you can use symbols like ***=**, **$=** or **^=** .

```
[id^='cphSiteContentView_cphContentPanel_ucBookingSummary_ucShoppingCart_rptProductList_ctl00_0_ucTravellersContactDetails_0_rptRoomsDetails_0_rptAdultDetails']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try use the regular expression, like
.//*[starts-with(@id,'cphSiteContentView_cphContentPanel_ucBookingSummary_ucShoppingCart_rptProductList_ctl00_0_ucTravellersContactDetails_0_rptRoomsDetails_0_rpt']
```